I can't get this GEE app to work when I publish it
I am very new to GEE. After the app is published, I access it through the link and get a flat map centered in the USA without any of the options programmed in the script.
It's basically a study on 12 points of the NDVI time series from 2020 to 2024. The idea is for the app user to be able to interact with the points and be able to obtain a plot with the time series of the point they click on.
The script does that when I run it, but after publishing, the app offers nothing.
// Load the area of interest and display it
var campo = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/numeric-dialect-419011/assets/padron_3962_claudia').geometry();
Map.centerObject(campo, 12);
Map.addLayer(campo, {color: 'gray'}, 'Area of Interest');

// Set the date range and load Sentinel-2 images
var startDate = '2020-01-01';
var endDate = '2024-01-01';
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
                .filterBounds(campo)
                .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                .map(function(image) {
                  return image.clip(campo);
                });

// Calculate and visualize NDVI
var ndvi = dataset.map(function(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI'));
});
var ndviVis = {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(ndvi.median().select('NDVI'), ndviVis, 'NDVI'); // Ensure only the 'NDVI' band is selected

// Visualize true color image
var trueColorVis = {bands: ['B4', 'B2', 'B3'], max: 4000};
Map.addLayer(dataset.median(), trueColorVis, 'True Color');

// Define and visualize points of interest
var points = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-57.23236811941059,-33.078842641353845]), {name: 'Point 1'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-57.22627414052875,-33.08409259193794]), {name: 'Point 2'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-57.22936404531391,-33.088623119281436]), {name: 'Point 3'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-57.25528491323383,-33.09121188724903]), {name: 'Point 4'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-57.2466160136977,-33.08279811268316]), {name: 'Point 5'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-57.25219500844867,-33.08632192821269]), {name: 'Point 6'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-57.242152817896915,-33.08905458590245]), {name: 'Point 7'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-57.254684098414494,-33.080281015145815]), {name: 'Point 8'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-57.254684098414494,-33.075965823207895]), {name: 'Point 9'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-57.26172221486957,-33.07510275941848]), {name: 'Point 10'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-57.236659653834415,-33.08215086591086]), {name: 'Point 11'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-57.22309840505512,-33.082618322390864]), {name: 'Point 12'})
]);
var pointStyle = {color: 'red', fillColor: '00000000'};
Map.addLayer(points, pointStyle, 'Points of Interest');

// Create a panel to display graphs and instructions
var panel = ui.Panel({style: {width: '400px', position: 'bottom-left'}});
var introLabel = ui.Label('Click on a point to view the NDVI time series.');
panel.add(introLabel);
ui.root.add(panel);

// Function to display graphs on the panel when a point is clicked
function showNDVIGraphs(point) {
  var pointData = ndvi.filterBounds(point.geometry());
  var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(pointData, point, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'NDVI', 10)
      .setChartType('LineChart')
      .setOptions({
        title: 'NDVI Time Series for ' + point.get('name').getInfo(),
        vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
        hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
        lineWidth: 1,
        colors: ['00FF00']
      });
  panel.clear();
  panel.add(introLabel); // Keep instructions visible
  panel.add(chart);
}

// Add a click listener to detect when a point is clicked nearby
Map.onClick(function(coords) {
  var clickPoint = ee.Geometry.Point([coords.lon, coords.lat]);
  var buffer = clickPoint.buffer(500); // Adjust as necessary

  points.filterBounds(buffer).evaluate(function(result) {
    if (result.features.length > 0) {
      var feature = ee.Feature(result.features[0]);
      showNDVIGraphs(feature);
    } else {
      panel.clear();
      panel.add(introLabel);
      panel.add(ui.Label('No nearby points detected.'));
    }
  });
});

Link: [https://code.earthengine.google.com/90675ffa834bbc28a09e740ee0b70177][1]

Your table needs to be public for the app (and the anonymous users of the app) to be able to see it.

Having ruled out an issue with the code, I revisited the sharing settings and found the problem. Thank you very much.

Go to the assets you're using, asset details > share > add app access
